# material ui button moves to a new line

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I have some text and a button (Popup) infront of it. Currently, there's no space between the text and the button. I want to have some space between the two items. If I try to put one of them in a division to put marginRight or marginLeft, the second object (button) moves to the next line. I want them both to be in the same line but with a space in between. How can I achieve this?

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  heading: {
    fontSize: "25px"
  },
  popup: {
    marginLeft: "20px"
  }
}));

export default function App() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className={classes.heading}>
        Instructions
        {/* <div className={classes.popup}> */}
        <Popup />
        {/* </div> */}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-hooks-yhik1?file=/src/App.js:0-638

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using flexbox?

On your styles update heading class to `display: flex`

```
  heading: {
   fontSize: "25px",
   display: "flex",
   alignItems: "center"
  },
```

Is this what you want to achieve?

Forked from your codesandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/embed/boring-northcutt-e0wdg?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark